# three.js: geometry.verticesNeedUpdate remains false despite setting to true

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to update a mesh which is currently on the canvas. When initialising the mesh I am setting the geometry to dynamic like so

```
mesh.geometry.dynamic = true;
```

I can print the mesh to console and check that dynamic in true.

To then update the mesh I use the set() function in a for loop

```
  for(i=0; i<6449; i++){
    x = this.model.geometry.vertices[i].x * parseFloat(eigen[count]);
    count++;
    y = this.model.geometry.vertices[i].y * parseFloat(eigen[count]);
    count++;
    z = this.model.geometry.vertices[i].z * parseFloat(eigen[count]);
    count++;
    this.model.geometry.vertices[i].set(x, y, z);
  }
```

At his stage I can check in console that the vertices have been updated with their new value.

Finally I set verticesNeedUpdate to true like so

```
this.model.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```

When I run this function the mesh is removed from the screen. Then which I check verticesNeedUpdate it is still set to false.

If I remove the verticesNeedUpdate = true; the mesh stays in the scene.

If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The flag verticesNeedUpdate can be set to true, which tells the renderer that they need to be updated. I believe this is done on the next render call, after which it is set back to false, so that it does not execute when no updates are needed. I am not sure why it is being removed from the scene.

Comment: @CoryGross thanks for the reply! Yes that makes sense. Shame we don't know why the new model isn't appearing.